# Calculate and remove duplicates of each unique row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A dataframe consists of more than 150,000 data includes duplicated data. In the following shows a sample of the data, with 25 columns (including index). I would like to:

1) calculate number of duplicates for each unique data

2) remove all the duplicated data based on each rows

3) insert a new column to display number of duplicates for each unique data

```
,Date,Time,Company,AV_ID,timestamp,Longitude,Latitude,Altitude,Roll,Pitch,Yaw,Roll Rate,Pitch Rate,Yaw Rate,Speed-x,Speed-y,Speed-z,Drive Mode,Throttle Actuator Value,Brake Light Condition,Brake Actuator Value,Steering Angle,Direction Indicator,Reverse Light Condition
0,29-Jan-2019,09:29:43.184,DEL,DEL0002,2019-01-29 09:33:33.425000,,,,,,,,0.0,,,2.22,,,9.25,,,,,
1,29-Jan-2019,09:29:43.184,in,msg:,should,be,20,or,18!,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,29-Jan-2019,09:29:43.199,DEL,DEL0002,2019-01-29 09:33:33.425000,,,,,,,,0.0,,,2.22,,,9.25,,,,,
3,29-Jan-2019,09:29:43.199,in,msg:,should,be,20,or,18!,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
4,29-Jan-2019,09:29:44.543,DEL,DEL0002,2019-01-29 09:33:35.425000,,,,,,,,0.0,,,2.5,,,7.63,,,,,
5,29-Jan-2019,09:29:44.543,in,msg:,should,be,20,or,18!,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
6,29-Jan-2019,09:29:44.574,DEL,DEL0002,2019-01-29 09:33:35.425000,,,,,,,,0.0,,,2.5,,,7.63,,,,,
7,29-Jan-2019,09:29:44.574,in,msg:,should,be,20,or,18!,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
8,29-Jan-2019,09:29:46.606,DEL,DEL0002,2019-01-29 09:33:37.425000,,,,,,,,0.0,,,2.22,,,5.48,,,,,
9,29-Jan-2019,09:29:46.606,in,msg:,should,be,20,or,18!,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10,29-Jan-2019,09:29:46.622,DEL,DEL0002,2019-01-29 09:33:37.425000,,,,,,,,0.0,,,2.22,,,5.48,,,,,
11,29-Jan-2019,09:29:46.622,in,msg:,should,be,20,or,18!,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
12,29-Jan-2019,09:29:48.573,DEL,DEL0002,2019-01-29 09:33:39.422000,,,,,,,,0.0,,,1.94,,,6.02,,,,,
13,29-Jan-2019,09:29:48.573,in,msg:,should,be,20,or,18!,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
14,29-Jan-2019,09:29:48.588,DEL,DEL0002,2019-01-29 09:33:39.422000,,,,,,,,0.0,,,1.94,,,6.02,,,,,
```

By far, I was able to remove the duplicates as follows. However, I am not able to calculate number of duplicates for each unique row of data and insert counts into a new column.

```
# To get some time conversion
s = pd.to_numeric(mydataset['timestamp'], errors = 'coerce') + local
mydataset['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(s, unit = 'ms')

# To remove the duplicates
duplicatedRows = mydataset[mydataset.duplicated()]
```

Comment: You can count the number of rows with duplicatedRows.count()

Comment: What I meant was I would like to count the number of occurrences for each identical row of data. For an example row 1 & row 2 have exactly identical data. That would make up to 2 counts for that particular data type. Row 3 to 5 are identical, thus count = 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I am right in what you want, looking at the following subset of your data:

```
4,29-Jan-2019,09:29:44.543,DEL,DEL0002,2019-01-29 09:33:35.425000,,,,,,,,0.0,,,2.5,,,7.63,,,,,
5,29-Jan-2019,09:29:44.543,in,msg:,should,be,20,or,18!,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
6,29-Jan-2019,09:29:44.574,DEL,DEL0002,2019-01-29 09:33:35.425000,,,,,,,,0.0,,,2.5,,,7.63,,,,,
```

If you want to consider the first and last of these lines as duplicates then you'll need to specify which columns to `groupby` as the times are different in the second column (09:29:44.543 and 09:29:44.574) so wouldn't group together.

Using a number of your columns as an example:

```
cols_to_groupby = ['Company', 'AV_ID', 'timestamp', 'Longitude', 'Latitude', 'Altitude']

# insert a new column with count of duplicates:
df['duplicate_count'] = df.groupby(cols_to_groupby).transform('count')

# get rid of duplicates:
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=cols_to_groupby)
```

Comment: This works! However, if I want to select more columns to groupby, I'm unable to do so. Could there be any other ways to work about?

Comment: What problem do you have if you try to add more columns to groupby?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `groupby` all columns and then count duplicates by `size`:

```
df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index(name='Size')
```

Comment: It gives me an error: "ValueError: Length of passed values is 130322, index implies 0". Could it be due to large amount of data?

Comment: It's perhaps each row in your dataset has at lease one `NAN`, see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23050#issuecomment-428002681). If it's possible, do `fillna` before `groupby`

Comment: glad to hear that. please consider accept/upvote the answer to make others easier to find the solution